# Multiprocessing Pool getting stuck

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I don`t have much experience with multiprocessing but thus far it seems to hate me.
I am trying to run the most simplest of examples, and yet it gets stuck and I have to restart my kernel.

My example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

aa = [x for x in range(3,16)]

def f(x):
    return x**2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with mp.Pool(processes = 4) as p:
        res = p.map(f, aa)

print(res)
```

It worked just fine up until I experimented with using class methods and atributes inside of the `pool.map()`.
I think that it broke after I tried to execute this:

```
class clasy():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def gen(self):
        for i in range(self.a, self.b):
            yield i

    def dodo(self):
        gg = gen()
        with mp.Pool() as pool:
            self.res = pool.map(f, gg)
        return self.res

paralel = clasy(3,16)
print(paralel.dodo())
```

What went wrong and can it be fixed?

And further more, is it possible to use class method for generator inside of the pool.map(), can it be used inside a class. Or should the pool, function and iterator be top level objects?

Comment: I don't see code snippet which is NOT working for you

Comment: @mad_ the code snippet you are seeing, the only on that is attached is NOT working for me, but I can try and replicate the  code that broke multiprocessing.

Comment: i don't think you can access the same variable with multiple processes. `res` should be a queue of some sort

Comment: @Finn I have no understanding of queue in multiprocessing, but even so, why did it work earlier?

Comment: @Peter did you solve it? for me, it was a memory issue, are you sure you have enough? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75784038/python-multiprocessing-application-is-getting-stuck-in-docker-container

Answer (score 0):

You need to either pass the function `f` to the class `clasy` or make it as an instance of the class. For example, the following should work:

```
class clasy():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def gen(self):
        for i in range(self.a, self.b):
            yield i

    def f(self, x):
        return x**2

    def dodo(self):
        gg = self.gen()
        with mp.Pool(processes = 4) as pool:
            self.res = pool.map(self.f, gg)
        return self.res

paralel = clasy(3,16)
print(paralel.dodo())

Out[1]:
[9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225]
```

Comment: I have tried something like this before, and all I got was pickling errors. But whats even better is that this example gets stuck as well. I don`t think that this question is about correct syntax or use anymore, the problem seems to be rooted somewhere deeper, and now I require a way to get back to a state in which I could be able to run anything in parralel.

Comment: That's weird. I tested the above code and it works fine on my machine. Do you have the error message when you run the code?

Comment: No, it just begins the process and never finishes it.